# How should we automate system testing?

Tags: testing, selenium, cucumber, salesforce, specflow

We are building a large CRM system based on the SalesForce.com cloud. I am trying to put together a test plan for the system but I am unsure how to create system-wide tests. I want to use some behaviour-driven testing techniques for this, but I am not sure how I should apply them to the platform.

For the custom parts we will build in the system I plan to approach this with either Cucumber of SpecFlow driving Selenium actions on the UI. But for the SalesForce UI Customisations, I am not sure how deep to go in testing. Customisations such as Workflows and Validation Rules can encapsulate a lot of complex logic that I feel should be tested.

Writing Selenium tests for this out-of-box functionality in SalesForce seems overly burdensome for the value. Can you share your experiences on System testing with the SalesForce.com platform and how should we approach this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is the problem with detailed test plan up front. You trying to guess what kind of errors, how many, and in what areas you will get. This may be tricky.

Maybe you should have overall Master Test Plan specifying only test strategy, main tool set, risks, relative amount of how much testing you want to put in given areas (based on risk).
Then when you starting to work on given functionality or iteration (I hope you are doing this in iterations not waterfall), you prepare detailed test plan for this set of work. You adjust your tools/estimates/test coverage based on experiences from previous parts.
This way you can say at the beginning what is your general approach and priorities, but you let yourself adapt later as project progresses.

Question about how much testing you need to put into testing [COTS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commercial_off-the-shelf) is the same as with any software: you need to evaluate the risk.

1. If your software need to be
   [Validated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Validation_%28drug_manufacture%29) because of external
   regulations ([FDA](http://www.fda.gov/medicaldevices/deviceregulationandguidance/guidancedocuments/ucm085281.htm),[DoD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIL-STD-498)..)
   you will need to go deep with your
   tests, almost test entire app. One
   problem here may be ensuring
   external regulator, that tools you
   used for validation are validated
   (and that is a troublesome).
2. If your application is
   mission-critical for your company,
   than you still need to do a lot of
   testing based on extensive risk
   analysis.
3. If your application is not concerned
   with all above, you can go with
   lighter testing. Probably you can
   skip functionality that was tested
   by platform manufacturer, and focus
   on your customisations. On the other
   hand I would still write tests (at
   least [happy paths](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_path)) for
   workflows you will be using in your
   business processes.

Answer (score 0):

When we started learning Selenium testing in 2008 we created Recruiting application from SalesForce handbook and created a suite of tests and described our path step by step in our [blog](http://www.deepshiftlabs.com/sel_blog/?page_id=279&lang=en-us). It may help you get started if you decide to write Selenium code to test your app.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem with SalesForce is you have Unit and UI testing, but no Service-level testing.  The SpecFlow I've seen which drives Selenium UI is brittle and doesn't encapsulate what I'm after in engineering a service-level test solution:

( When I navigate to "/Selenium-Testing-Cookbook-Gundecha-Unmesh/dp/1849515743"
 And I click the 'buy now' button
 And then I click the 'proceed to checkout' button)

That is not the spirit or intent of Specflow.

Given I have not selected a product
When I select Proceed to Checkout
Then ensure I am presented with a message

In order to test that with selenium, you essentially have to translate that to clicks and typing, whereas in the .NET realm, you can instantiate objects, etc., in the middle-tier, and perform hundreds of instances and derivations against the same BACKGROUND (mock setup).

I'm told that you can expose SF through an API at some security risk.  I'd love to find more about THAT.